# C++ query regarding for loop iterations

Tags: c++, for-loop, prime-factoring

```
int sum = 2;
long long j;
for (j = 3; j <= 2000000; j+=2){
    bool stens = true;
    for (int k = 2; k < j; k++){
        if (j%k == 0){
            stens = false;
            break;}
        else stens = true;
    }
    if (stens){
        sum += j;
    }
}
cout << sum << endl;
cout << j << endl;
```

The above is a piece of C++ code that finds the sum of all prime numbers up to 2 million. However, the program takes forever to compile- I'm assuming this is because it has to iterate too many times (checking for 1 million numbers, and also checking if each one is a prime number). What can I do to fix this? Please note that my coding knowledge is pretty limited- I only started programming a month ago.

Thanks.

Comment: can you clarify? You're saying this code takes forever to *compile*, but I suspect you mean it takes a long time to *execute*, right?


Also note that the inner for loop needs to, at most, loop until `sqrt(j)`, not all the way to `j`

Comment: You can not check numbers larger than 1414 (sqrt(2000000)) in the second loop. It will be much faster.

Comment: In case you are talking about _execution_ time (opposed to compilation time), the answer for "_What can I do to fix this?_" Would be - picking a better prime detection algorithm. Iterating up until the actual number, is pretty much the worst algorithm there is.

Comment: @Zefick Or, to be more precise, to not check the numbers larger than `sqrt (j)`, in his code.

Comment: Also have a look at [Sieve of Eranthoses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Or, even better, replace the `k < j` condition with `k*k < j`: Depending on the architecture, `sqrt()` may take a while to calculate.

Comment: @cmaster Oh, never thought of it like that. Thank you fir pointing that out. You can learn something new, everyday, even about the simplest of things :)